# Problems with Maverick upgrade

Tags: 10.10, installation, memory, re-installation

I upgraded to Maverick 10.10 from Lucid. I have an old Toshiba Satellite with a 1.1 MHz and 256MB RAM. Initially I couldn't get my wireless to work. That solved itself after installing various updates and programs.

The problems that remain are:

1. I have to authorize at least 2 times at start-up. This machine is Ubuntu only. No boot load screen.
2. I have a ton of programs and system directories that are in my home folder. Is this normal?
3. It is difficult to wake the computer from sleep. Usually I just shut it down and restart. Tonight I waited and got a message about corrupt memory.
4. The computer takes forever to do just about everything. Slow to start programs or doing things on the web.

I am a longtime Mac user (since 1986). I also manage a network of several windows machines. I am definitely a GUI guy and do very little in the terminal so I really need to know where to begin to get things straightened out. Can I rescue this machine without wiping it and doing a fresh install? This is basically a hobby machine. Aside from all the programs and upgrades I've installed, I have almost no files or documents to worry about saving.

Anyone have any ideas about the problems I'm having and the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the facts the specs stated I would recommend Lubuntu for a less intensive-resource-heavy operation.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you mean directories like /usr /var /root and others, yes that's normal.
2. This could be incompatibilities between your computer and the system (although I doubt it)
3. 10.10 is not light on the system.  The issue being that since you have such little RAM and such a slow processor, its going to be slow on your system.  There are lighter builds of Ubuntu, but I personally don't know what they are.

Comment: Lighter builds of Ubuntu include Lubuntu (with LXDE) and Xubuntu (with Xfce). You can also continue to use Ubuntu and load a less heavy desktop environment such as Window Maker or IceWM. I've never used LXDE, but from my experience, Xfce, Window Maker, and IceWM are all quite robust and usable.

Comment: Thanks to @David for being more specific with information